# Node.js sequelize calling a stored procedure with input and output parameters

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

**Database Query :**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `signinVendor`(in inputvalue varchar(100), in pword varchar(30), **out retval tinyint**)
BEGIN
```

**Node.js Code :**

```
const spquery = await db.sequelize.query('call signinVendor(:inputvalue,:pword,**@retval**);',{
    replacements:{
      inputvalue : req.body.inputvalue,
      pword : req.body.password
    },
    type: QueryTypes.SELECT,
    raw: true
  });
```

I am able to call procedures by entering the input value and password. But, I am unable to find syntax to access the return value through my sequelize nodejs code. How do we write code for out parameter in sequelize?

Comment: What is the value of `spquery` after the call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it seems that we can pre write code and send output via select in database and avoid using output parameter. It seems Sequelize ORM has not yet implemented any way to accesss the output parameter through NodeJS.

FOR EXAMPLE:

IN SQL,

instead of creating an out parameter in stored procedure, you can use parameters to store your desired output.

set query = (select count(*) from table_name);

Then you can perform select without parameter like :

select query ;

This way you don't need to rely on output parameter in Sequelize ORM. You can simply select your desired output as the outcome of the stored procedure.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).